# Windows Error 3 : The system cannot find the path specified pyinstaller

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I have converted a .py file to an .exe file.  When I run the .exe file on my computer it works well.  When I try another PC it does not work. It says Line 16 by the way. First block below is my code. Second one is the error.

```
import sys, os 
def resource_path(relative_path):
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, relative_path)
    return os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), relative_path)
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.filedialog import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import numpy as np 
import numpy.random.common
import numpy.random.bounded_integers
import numpy.random.entropy
import pandas as pd 
# Change working directory
pathwd = "E:\\Desktop\\tkinter final backups\\Machine Learning Implementing Program"
os.chdir(pathwd)
```

> WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'E:\Desktop\tkinter final backups\Machine Learning Implementing Program'

Comment: If the other computer has no e: drive, then there is no way to find the path with the .py or .exe file. Also, if they have not created that directory, you will get an error. I think you can just type cd "e:\desktop\tkinter final backups\machine learning implementing program" on the other computer to verify this. It seems like it might be better to allow the user to specify a drive or path, or to use a try/except block to catch if the directory is not there.

Comment: Maybe i can create it on the desktop, so everyone has C:\\Desktop, by the way how can i write try: except: function for this can you help me ?

Comment: try: /// os.chdir(pathwd) /// except: /// print ("I can't find this directory, so I'll try something else."  ... (you need indents for os and print, but the basic idea is, it lets you catch an error and keep going.) In your case, you could try: (goto directory #1) then except: (os.mkdir directory #2, os.chdir directory #2)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because the other system does not have the same directory as your system has.

Comment: Absolutely, the problem is that but, i need to define a unique directory maybe, so the other ones can run this exe too.

Comment: Yes.. you should add that in your question, asking how can you make a unique directory, so that the program can execute in other systems too.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem with these codes below ,

```
pathwd = "C:"+os.environ["HOMEPATH"]+"\\Desktop"

os.chdir(pathwd)
```

But now i have another problem :) . In my tkinter project it has some images. But when i open a page on the exe file it says for example The system cannot find the path specified "abcdef.jpeg" how can i embed a picture in exe?